# How to map correctly to make `x-hasura-allowed-roles` field an array using claims_map in Hasura?

Tags: hasura, hasura-docker, hasura-jwt

I have a JWT token which looks like

```
{
  "aud": "xx",
  "iss": "http://xx.com/adfs/services/trust",
  "iat": 1649956864,
  "exp": 1649960464,
  "apptype": "xx",
  "appid": "dcf6c0d8-7f3c-4904-a0c9-852c92c7624f",
  "authmethod": "http://xx",
  "auth_time": "2022-04-14T17:21:04.095Z",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

I am trying to map `appid` into `x-hasura-allowed-roles` field as an item of an array by using `claims_map` in Hasura.

```
HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: '{"jwk_url":"xx","claims_map":{"x-hasura-allowed-roles":{"path":"$.appid"},"x-hasura-default-role":{"path":"$.appid"}}}'
```

Note this part inside:

```
"x-hasura-allowed-roles":{"path":"$.appid"}
```

I will get this error when I query

> invalid x-hasura-allowed-roles; should be a list of roles: parsing [] failed, expected Array, but encountered String

which makes sense, because `x-hasura-allowed-roles` needs to be an array.

### First Try (Failed)

If I change to

```
"x-hasura-allowed-roles":[{"path":"$.appid"}]
```

When I start Hasura, I will get the error

> Fatal Error:- Environment variable HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: Error in $['claims_map'][0]: parsing String failed, expected String, but encountered Object

### Second Try (Failed)

```
"x-hasura-allowed-roles":{"path":["$.appid"]}
```

> Fatal Error:- Environment variable HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: Error in $['claims_map'].path: parsing Text failed, expected String, but encountered Array

How to map correctly to make `x-hasura-allowed-roles` field an array? Thanks

Comment: Maybe the error is on other element. Can you please post you entire jwt structure that you tried, not just the allowed roles part ?

Comment: @lokeshkumar just changed to entire jwt structure.

Comment: Do you have any control over the JWT to make that field in array form? I've filled this github issue https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/8402

Comment: @ArjunYelamanchili Unfortunately, I don't have that control. Thanks for creating the GitHub ticket!

Comment: I'm not sure the timeline of getting that change in but Im optimistic it will eventually, in the mean time if you don't control the JWT you'll probably have to use the webhook auth mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Arjun Yelamanchili helped create a GitHub ticket at https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/8402

---

Here is a temp solution, I ended up with hardcoding `x-hasura-allowed-roles` like

```
HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: '{"jwk_url":"xx","claims_map":{"x-hasura-allowed-roles":["dcf6c0d8-7f3c-4904-a0c9-852c92c7624f"],"x-hasura-default-role":{"path":"$.appid"}}}'
```

It is more strict.

However, I feel it might not be necessary, as we will define each appid permissions in Hasura UI. Also, I need update `HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET` each time when I onboard a new app.